# Socket.IO emit on Express 4 route

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm trying to send messages to my all connected clients with socket.io from express 4 routes. All my routes on same file, it's cloned from official [socket.io chat example](https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example). I want to emit a "announcement" message to my all recently connected clients.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    io.sockets.emit('chat message', "ANNOUNCEMENT : ..."); // <-- HERE
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

But it's not emitting message and I don't see anything on console. I've moved my routes to another file and passing `io` object to route as parameter, but it's still not working. It's working if I emit message from client side JavaScript.

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "1.2.0"
  }
```

## Steps to reproduce problem with chat example

1. `git clone https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example.git`
2. `cd chat-example && npm install`
3. `nano index.js`
4. Change content of index.js with my code above
5. `node index.js`
6. Browse to `localhost:3000`, you should see a announcement on chat panel because I'm emitting it on `app.get()` route. But there is no announcement.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Can you show us the client-side code?  Are you trying to broadcast to all connected clients?

Comment: I'm trying to send message (emit) from my routes to all connected clients. @jfriend00

Comment: Does your browser get `index.html` properly when you hit the `/` route?  Also, `io.emit('chat message', "msg")` is the proper way to send to all connected clients.  If you put a `console.log("got / route")` in the `app.get()` handler, do you see that?  You need to tell us what basic debugging steps you've already done and what you observed.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes it's rendering index.html properly. So my route working, but emit() code isn't working. You can try it by cloning https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example repo and changing index.js's content with mine.

Comment: Show us your client socket.io code.

Comment: @jfriend00 , I just add steps to reproduce the problem, please check out  the question again. Because I think you misunderstood. Here my client side code : https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are emitting to the new page too soon in this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    io.sockets.emit('chat message', "ANNOUNCEMENT : ..."); // <-- HERE
});
```

The new page has not yet finished making it's socket.io connection so it won't get the `.emit()`.  In fact, because `res.sendFile()` is asynchronous, the new page may not have even started making its socket.io connection yet.

You're doing the `.emit()` as soon as the `res.sendFile()` is initiated, but if you put `console.log()` statements into your server code, you will see that that occurs BEFORE the connection arrives.  So, you're emitting before the client has actually finished making it's socket.io connection.

If you intend to send something upon page initialization, then you should do it in the server-side `io.on('connection', ...)` handler because that's where you know the new page is now connected.

Comment: After your answer I've changed `app.get()` method to be sure emit occurring when page loaded completely. But nothing changed. Here my codes : http://paste.ubuntu.com/16669943/

Comment: @Eray - That's still too soon.  Now you're emitting when `res.sendFile()` has finished, but that just means that Express has finished writing the file to the TCP stack.  It doesn't mean the browser has received it, parsed it, run the scripts in it and that the socket.io connection has completed.  In fact, it's almost guaranteed that several of those things have not completed yet.  Please reread the last paragraph in my answer.  That's the only place you can "know" that a new socket.io connected is now ready for you to `.emit()` to it.

Comment: @Eray - Did this answer your question?

Comment: jfriend, I'm still working on the project but I had to give a week break because of other tasks. But I'll back here of course and accept your answer after trying it.

Comment: @Eray - Well this place doesn't work very well when there's 4 days between correspondence.